# Call native method from Swift that has uint8_t ** as output parameter

Tags: swift, pointers, interop, pointer-to-pointer

I have a C method with the interface

```
size_t foo(uint8_t ** output)
```

This gets imported to Swift as

```
func foo(_ output: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>) -> Int
```

How can I call this method from Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `foo()` allocates an `uint8_t` array, puts the address
into the memory location pointed to by `output`, and returns the
size of the allocated array, you can use it 
from Swift like this

```
var output : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = nil
let size = foo(&output)
for i in 0 ..< size {
    println(output[i])
}
```

You will also have to decide who is responsible for releasing the
allocated memory. If the `foo()` functions allocates it using
`malloc()` then you can release it from Swift with

```
free(output)
```

Comment: Isn't foo's parameter pointer to a pointer, instead of pointer to UInt8 ?

Comment: @DejanSkledar: `var output : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` is the Swift equivalent of a pointer to UInt8. It is passed as "inout parameter" `&output` to `foo()`, which is the Swift equivalent of passing the address of a variable. – Roughly speaking: `output` is a pointer to UInt8 and `&output` is a pointer to a pointer to UInt8.

Comment: yes, but UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>> is in Swift equivalent of a pointer to an array of UInt8's , right?

Comment: @DejanSkledar: No, `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>>` is a pointer to a pointer. – I have tested the above code and it works as expected (if my assumptions about what foo() does are correct).

Comment: I thought that foo() takes a pointer to an array, but anyway, it should work both ways.